# 3D Bar Plot of dictionary in Python

Tags: python, dictionary, plot, 3d

There is a dictionary like : a = {('1','2'): 10, ('3','4'): 20, ('8','11'): 85, ...}
I want to have a 3D bar plot in python such that the first number in key section to be in x axis and the second number in key section to be in y axis and the value to be in z axis. For example, ('1','2'): 10  means x=1, y=2, z=3
The problems that I have in writing the Python code to have a 3D bar plot is:

1. Keys are string and I could not use int() for them because indexing dictionaries is a bit different.
2. There are about 500 000 point and I do not know how to handle them. It will occupy my RAM if I put all in a list at once.

Answer (score 0):

To make the plot you will need to have `x,y` and `z` in three different lists:

```
x, y, z = [], [], []
for k, v in a.iteritems():
    x.append(int(k[0]))
    y.append(int(k[1]))
    z.append(v)
```

If you have a memory problem you can sample some values, for example at the beginning of the for loop insert a condition like:

```
from random import randint

for k, v in a.iteritems():
    if randint(0,9)==9:
        continue
    ...
```

This will get you 1/10 of the points.